# Method can't delete Map element when used in OnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing with Angular atm. I have a component.ts thats implements OnInit and a Service which has an observable Map object. The ngOnInit()-method subscribes to the Observable and should call a certain method from the Service if the Observable is changed. That method returns a copy of the Map object with a specific element removed. My problem is: When I call the method in ngOnInit(), the just returns the Map object without removal of that specific element. Everywhere else it works as it should.

**Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {

  constructor() { }
 
  private _attrInputSubject = new Subject<Map<number, string>>();
  attrInputData$ = this._attrInputSubject.asObservable();
  
  idIndex: number = 0;
  attrInputs: Map<number, string> = new Map([
    [0, 'elem1'],
    [1, 'elem2'],
    [2, 'elem3'],
    [3, 'elem4'],
    [4, 'elem5']
  ]);
  
  getAttrMinusID(): Map<number, string> {
    let tempAttr = new Map(this.attrInputs);
    tempAttr.delete(this.idIndex);
    return tempAttr;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {

  graph: ForceDirectedGraph;

  constructor(private _settingsService: SettingsService) {}
  
  addNode(tag: string) {
    let tempNode = new Node(0, tag);
    tempNode.networkAttr = this._settingsService.getAttrMinusID();
    this.graph.addNewNode(tempNode);
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this._settingsService.attrInputData$.subscribe(inputs => {
      for (let i=0; i<this.graph.nodes.length; i++) {
        this.graph.nodes[i].networkAttr = this._settingsService.getAttrMinusID();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The call in the addNode()-method works just fine. Those classes are obviously longer than this, I removed most of the things unrelated to the problem for visibility.

Comment: the code is confusing. Inside the service you are calling the same service which will change the observable!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did you mean to say inside the component?